# Insert a multiline string with arbitrary special characters to a template file in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Something like:

`cat template.txt | ruby -e 'puts STDIN.read.sub("%placeholder%", IO.read("content.txt"))' > output.txt`

Or:

```
ed template.txt <<EOF
/%placeholder%/d
.r content.txt
w output.txt
EOF
```

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[me@home]$ sed -e '/\$xxx/r content.txt' -e '/\$xxx/d' template.txt 
.,:;-+=_'"`*^?!
.,:;-+=_'"`*^?!
&$%#@|/\()[]{}<>
&$%#@|/\()[]{}<>
```

The first command searches for `$xxx` then  prints out the contents of `content.txt`. The second one deletes `$xxx`.

You can also use a multi-line command, which would be more readable when used in scripts.

```
sed -e '/\$xxx/{
   r content.txt
   d
}' template.txt
```